# functions that supposed to be executed on submit do not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up web page (sign in page) where the user supposed to fill his personal info (just like a regular sign in page) but, the main purpose here is to check whether the user submitted his data properly and if not he would be notified by an alert message. My problem is with the functions which for some reason sometimes works and sometimes do not work.

*The code is not fully completed but I can't continue with basic errors such as mine*

I tried to find the solution in Stack Overflow and lots of js tutorials. Tried find a missing ";" or any other basic mistake that a beginner can do.

```js
function goSign() {
  var src = "signinpage.html"
  window.open(src);
}

function checkAge() {

  const x = document.forms["ageForm"]["age"].value;
  const regex = /^\d{2}$/;
  if (!x.match(regex)) {
    alert("Must input numbers not longer than 2 digits");
    return false;
  }
}

function checkUsern() {

  const username = document.forms["userForm"]["username"].value;
  const regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
  alert(
    return namelen);
  var minlen = 10;

  if (minlen > username.length) {
    alert("Your username must have atleast 10 characters");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Signin</h1>
<p>Please fill your details as requested</p><br>

<form name="nameForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkName()" method="post">
  Full Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" />
</form>

<form name="ageForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkAge()" method="post">
  Age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="age" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="userForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkUsern()" method="post">
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" /><br>

</form>
```

The expected output from those functions is, let's say the user entered a 3 digit number in his Age so he should be alerted "Must input numbers not longer than 2 digits", but instead the input just disappears and nothing happens.
Same thing with username.

Note: my main goal to do only 1 submit button that checks all the user's input but i dont know how to do it so instead i just apply a function and a submit button for every user input to make sure that the functions work properly...

Comment: Couple of suggestions. Add the script tag just before the closing of the body tag. Add the missing closing `}` for `checkUsern` function.

Comment: Only your second form has a submit button. The first and last don't have any way to submit - is this intentional? if not, add another "<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>" to each form. Or, if you only want 1 submit button total, only use one form that validates each input. Also, your onSubmit only needs to have your function - so you should be able to change "return checkUsern()" to just "checkUsern()".

Comment: Click the Run code snippet and you'll see you have at least one syntax error in your code. You should see this locally in your browser if you press F12 while running your code.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Right now the only thing that can submit is `age`. If you're trying to put all of this into one form you need to wrap it in one `form`. Secondly, don't put `return` in your `alert` call. We can help, but this doesn't make a whole lot of sense until you explain the intention.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies within `return checkName()` in the `onsubmit` handler for your inputs

The handler expects a function, so you should be fine to just write `onsubmit="checkName"`

Comment: there's a lot more wrong than that. the `alert` has a `return` in it, for instance. Plus there are three forms and only one submit. Edit: Also, `return checkName()` isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: It also looks like there's a missing function called checkName. Or, it isn't displayed in the code they included.